# Expand function into a Maclaurin's series

Tags: taylor-expansion

The function is given with:

$f(x)=\dfrac{x^{2012}}{(1-x^3)^2}$

I have no idea what to do here and honestly, I don't really understand what a Maclaurin's series is. I know the definition but I don't understand the concept enough to be able to solve problems like this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I don't really understand what a Maclaurin's series is." There is not much to understand, but just to read. Given a function $f(x)$ defined on a neighborhood of the origin (that is, an interval $(-\delta,\delta)$ for some $\delta >0$) and infinitely differentiable on $x=0$, we define its Maclaurin series to be $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$

That is, you *compute* what $f^{(n)}(0)$ is and plug that in into a power series.

Comment: @Peter, but hardly the quickest way of doing it. You can use the (known) binomial-series expansion for $(1+X)^{-2}$ and substitute $X=-x^3$, then multiply the whole mess by $x^{2012}$. If OP needs only a few (like a dozen) terms of the series, he can simply divide the polynomial $1-2x^3+x^6$ into $x^{2012}$, by using the method he learned in high-school, except writing the terms in *ascending* order of degree instead of descending.

Comment: @Lubin I was not suggesting that he brute force computed $f^{(n)}(0)$, my point was that the definition of Maclaurin series is not something you have to *understand*, since there is little to understand from it. André's solution is what I would have suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are undoubtedly familiar with the geometric series expansion 
$$\frac{1}{1-t}=1+t+t^2+t^3+t^4+\cdots,$$
valid for $|t|\lt 1$. Differentiate with repect to $t$. We get
$$\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}=1+2t+3t^2+4t^3+\cdots.$$
Put $t=x^3$. We get the expansion of $\dfrac{1}{(1-x^3)^2}$.

Then multiply term by term by $x^{2012}$.

**Remark:** In principle, we could also find the series expansion by differentiating our function $f(x)$ repeatedly, and using the fact that the Maclaurin series is 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n,$$
where $f^{(n)}(x)$ is the $n$-th derivative of $f(x)$. That would in this case be quite a bit harder than the approach we took above.

Once we know the Maclaurin series for a few familiar and important functions, most of the time we use manipulations of known series instead of going back to fundamentals.

Comment: Ok. I've done what you said but the result doesn't really look like the generic Maclaurin series you wrote. It doesn't have the factorial and I can't really tell which part of it (if any) is the $f^{(n)}(0)$. Am I supposed to apply some other transformation?

Comment: Differentiating repeatedly is not practical. But you might try for the expansion of $g(t)=\frac{1}{1-t}$ by differentiating repeatedly. You will find that a factorial appears in the numerator $g^{(n)}(0)$, which cancels the factorial in the denominator. If you do precisely as I suggested, you will get the right series, a series that would be exceedingly unpleasant to obtain by repeated differentiation.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First try to find the Taylor expansion for $\frac{1}{1-x^3}$ (use substitution and the Taylor expansion for $\frac{1}{1-x}$). Now differentiate term-by-term to get an expression  for $\frac{3x^2}{(1-x^3)^2}$. Finally, multiply through by some power of $x$ (2010 I think) and divide by 3.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the Taylor series, at some point $a$, is given by

$$f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x - a)^2 + \frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x - a)^3 + \cdots,$$

then, the MacLaurin Series is simply the Taylor series at $a = 0$, i.e

$$f(0) + f'(0)(x-0) + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}(x - 0)^2 + \frac{f'''(0)}{3!}(x - 0)^3 + \cdots$$
$$= f(0) + f'(0)(x) + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}(x)^2 + \frac{f'''(0)}{3!}(x)^3 + \cdots.$$

So now, to answer your question, you need to simply "fill in the gaps" to the above series and see if you can put it in some kind of summation form.